# How do I change my name via the command-line of the Minecraft.exe?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change player name in minecraft multiplayer in offline mode in Linux?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24543/how-to-change-player-name-in-minecraft-multiplayer-in-offline-mode-in-linux)

I installed some mods for Minecraft recently, and because of this I can only run the game using the EXE. But the problem with that is I can no longer use the old .bat trick and create a script to change my name. How can I change my name using the command-line of the Minecraft.exe?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24543/how-to-change-player-name-in-minecraft-multiplayer-in-offline-mode-in-linux/

Comment: Well, if the other question answered your question it's a dupe almost by definition :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to confirm that this is **not** possible via the command-line, but there are some suggestion in [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24543/how-to-change-player-name-in-minecraft-multiplayer-in-offline-mode-in-linux) that can help you, maybe?

Edit: Just noticed bckbck posted the link as a comment, but I'll leave this in my answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to find a launcher that will allow me to change my name, and launch the .exe :)

Comment: Thanks Juan! That was really weird, I've never had that happen before.