# How do I change player name in Minecraft smp in offline mode on a Mac?

Tags: macos, minecraft-java-edition

This post pretty much summarizes my question : [How do I change player name in minecraft multiplayer in offline mode in Linux?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24543/how-do-i-change-player-name-in-minecraft-multiplayer-in-offline-mode-in-linux)

I know for a fact that Mac and Linux are both Unix based

And the commands for Linux should work for Mac, but with limited knowledge for programming I couldn't get it to work.

EDIT: Just saw this - http://pepijndevos.nl/2011/08/11/playing-minecraft-offline.html#fnref:1
currently working on it

Comment: Any particular reason you unaccepted my answer? I'm happy to provide more information if you need it.

Comment: A lot of these answers are very dated, and I don’t believe any of them apply to a modern version of Minecraft—at least because I tried the solutions listed and couldn’t get them to work.  While I really tried to use the official launcher, in the end I used MultiMC.  MultiMC allows you to change your player’s name very simply —at least in the offline case—and you can even do it easily every time you play the game.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it, but not through the Minecraft launcher. Open TextEdit and make sure it's in plain text mode. If it isn't, choose "Make Plain Text" from the Format menu. Then enter the following text:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp "bin/*" -Djava.library.path="bin/natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "YOURNAMEHERE"
```

Replace `YOURNAMEHERE` with the name you want, but keep it in quotes. Now save your file, and make sure you uncheck the box that says "If no extension is provided, use '.txt'." Save the file as `launcher.command` (you can call it whatever you wish, just make sure it ends with `.command`).

Now in order to make this launchable with a double-click, open up Terminal and type `sudo chmod 777` and then drag and drop your file on to the Terminal window. Then press Return. It will prompt you for your password, which you should enter. You can now close Terminal.

The file will now be executable, so you can run it by double-clicking. It will open Minecraft in offline mode with the custom name. If you ever want to change the name, right-click the file and choose Open With > TextEdit. You can then edit the name and save the file, and it will use the new name.

Comment: Getting error "Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.Minecraft
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.client.Minecraft"

Answer (score 2):

For a temporary fix, try this command through terminal. Handy when you just want to get some friends changed so you can all play via LAN!

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -cp "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\*" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "NAME_HERE"
```

Comment: This isnt working! Can you supply an updated command for 1.2.5 the full release?? :) I need this for a school project...