# How do I change my offline name on the mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change player name in Minecraft smp in offline mode on a Mac?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32813/how-do-i-change-player-name-in-minecraft-smp-in-offline-mode-on-a-mac)

I want to change my offline name in MineCraft on my mac.

I have only found ways to change it on Linux and Windows. Is there any way I can change my offline username on my mac?