# Minecraft 1.16.4 LAN game: two players with one account

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Me and a friend tried to play a offline world in LAN mode, but the game kicks one player out because we have the same nickname.
Is there a way to play without having to buy another copy of the game?
Launcher version is 2.2.911

Comment: Try this: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/130957

Comment: I already stumbled upon that question, but with no luck. Seems like they have patched this thing

Comment: In 1.16 it is in "launcher_accounts.json". Change "name": "<playername>", to "name": "<newname>"

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per TheKodeToad's comment (after resolving a duplicate chain)

Answer (score 2):

No there is not. The mc account can only be on one server at a time.

Sorry man, seems you will have to buy another account. I hope i was able to help!