# How do I change my player name in Minecraft multiplayer in offline mode in Windows

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I change my name in Minecraft multiplayer offline mode in windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change player name in minecraft multiplayer in offline mode in Linux?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24543/how-do-i-change-player-name-in-minecraft-multiplayer-in-offline-mode-in-linux)

Answer (score 4):

Open up a notepad file, and put this command into it.

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\*" \
-Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\natives" \
net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "yourusername"
```

Replace `yourusername` with whatever name you wish. Save the notepad file as `CUSTOMNAME.bat`

You can use that file to now run minecraft with your name changed. (you may have to go into your folder options and enable the viewing of system files to see the customname.bat after you have saved it depending on your current windows settings)

Comment: In 1.6.4 (latest release right now), I'm doing this but in the game it says "version 1.5" in the corner.  When run through the launcher, it's fine.  I'm almost positive I shouldn't even *have* version 1.5 on this computer.  Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score -4):

The easiest way that I know of is to use a cracked client. That way you can easily change your username and keep track of different usernames that you have used on different servers.