# Can both my boys have a user on minecraft PC.

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My son got MineCraft PC for his birthday.  The account is under my e-mail and he has a name in the game (my terminology may be off as i do not play the game).  My other son would also like to play MineCraft, but have his own name (character???).  Can that be done?  It doesn't seem logical that I'd have to download 2 Minecraft games.  Please let me know how this works.

Comment: You'll have to buy a copy of the game per son (though you'll need another email address, too) This is the only legitimate way to have two characters with different names. If this isn't an option, they can have a 'world' each and use the same character & name, though if they do this they won't be able to take full advantage of the multiplayer stuff.

Answer (score 20):

Really depends on your use case.

You only need one copy of the actual game installed if they are taking turns playing.

If you want them to play multiplayer, you will need to purchase two accounts, one for each kid. This also allows them to easily have their own name and "skin" in game.

However, if they just want their own names, you can create two shortcuts to the game, one for each kid. Then just give a different name for each shortcut. See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74263/how-do-i-change-my-player-name-in-minecraft-multiplayer-in-offline-mode-in-windo) on creating the shortcuts.

Comment: The command in that link apparently doesn't work since 1.6

Comment: I think you mean *one account for each kid* not two.

Comment: @Colin Undoubtedly. Fixed!

Answer (score 15):

You don't have to download Minecraft twice, but you do have to buy a second account if you want them to have separate accounts. They'll be able to play on the same copy of Minecraft with their own accounts, or they can play on different computers at the same time (even together, in multiplayer).

On the other hand, they could just play on the same account. They will have to take turns using the account as one account can't log in on different computers at the same time, and they won't be able to have different names or characters.

Comment: they'll be able to go into each other's worlds and sabotage it if they use the same PC account, ofcourse that is only a problem if they are the type to do so. if you want to defend against that then have a different PC profile for each of them

Comment: @ratchetfreak Nothing prevents one son from booting linux and messing around with a world anyway.

Comment: @nightcracker target of opportunity is in effect here: if the kid sees the world of the sibling each time they start playing it is very tempting to go in and start griefing, if a workaround of booting a live linux CD and finding the .minecraft folder is required it is much less likely to do so

Comment: @ratchetfreak The new launcher has a per-profile option to use a different working folder, allowing completely separate installs and saves.

Answer (score 2):

If, like you said, they want there own name then you will definitely have to buy a second account (or game) to have legitimate different names. There is no need to completely re download the game, as there is a login setting when the game is opened, allowing them to simply enter in their information when it is their turn.

There is only one benefit of really doing this:

- If you have multiple computers, both of them are able to play
  together through minecraft built in LAN service or play on the same
  multiplayer servers together. Plus they get their own names.

Other than that, it isn't really necessary. If you don't have another computer for them to use, then one account is all they need. They can create their own world and play on multiplayer server under the same character.

Answer (score -2):

I think that if you get an empty hard drive then you can just move Minecraft on to the hard drive then just plug the hard drive in to the other computer or laptop and that should work.

Comment: That would probably work, but I think the question was about running the game on the same computer with two different accounts.