# How can my two boys both play on Mineplex?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Both boys want to play Mineplex but one complains the other uses all his coins?
Is there any way to do this without repurchasing another Minecraft download?

Comment: Do they both use the same Minecraft account? If so, you would want to purchase them each their own accounts.

Comment: Very related:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123923/can-both-my-boys-have-a-user-on-minecraft-pc?rq=1   I don't know what Mineplex is, but the only way to have two users play on the same server without messing things up is if they have separate accounts.  If they're going to be sharing an account, they should probably never play on the same server.

Answer (score 2):

If there is any reason not to buy one separate account for each of them (which I recommend doing), you could simply establish real-life rules for them. For example, give them each a coin-spending limit, or tell them that they can only spend as many coins as they earn. It wouldn't give them as much freedom, but it would probably stop conflict over coin usage.

Answer (score 0):

Look up unmigrated accounts for sale. You can change the email password username skin and everything about the account, and it usually costs $2-3

Comment: This is of [questionable legality](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/209988/28182). As per [Minecraft's EULA](https://account.mojang.com/documents/minecraft_eula): *"The one major rule is that you must not distribute anything we've made. By "distribute anything we've made" what we mean is "give copies of the game away, make commercial use of, try to make money from, or let other people get access to our game and its parts in a way that is unfair or unreasonable"."*

Answer (score -2):

A god one is starting up mine-craft launcher 1.6.11 and going to new profile, change the name to whatever the kid wants it to be, then hit save profile and it should go to that, then in the bottom left corner there should be his username you just made, click on that and it will switch between both profiles, because mineplex has username recognition, they will both have their own individual coins! hope i helped :P

Comment: That's not how profiles work. When you create a new profile, it does not create a new username.

Comment: This works only if you *already* have two separate accounts to log into each profile with.