# How can I have two profiles, with two skins, in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I have two different profiles, with two different skins, in Minecraft? My two daughters want to play, and I don't want to download two copies of the game, or buy two accounts. They would be playing from different computers, too.

Comment: Umm, "accounts" and "profiles" are the same thing in Minecraft I'm afraid. However, the download is free, it's the accounts that cost. So you can download as many copies of Minecraft as you like, on as many PCs as you like. If you purchase two profiles/accounts, they can have their skins set individually.

Comment: @Ben Profiles and Accounts are two different things. A profile is a configuration of Minecraft attached to an account (you can have more than one per launcher), while an account is... Well, your credentials.

Comment: @Jala - In the long run it might be worth investing in a second account for your other daughter. See [this answer.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/209988/28182)

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, you get one user preferences account. You can set one skin per user at a time.

You can easily change skins online but it would still be the same user and all that entails.

Additionally, using the same account on two computers, although possible, is not advisable and in many cases not allowed. This is especially problematic if they try to connect to the same server or to play together on a LAN.

That all said, the best solution is to acquire a second account.