# Can I download Minecraft Windows 10 Edition on the same user account on different computers?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

To clarify, using the same account, would one be able to download Minecraft Windows 10 Edition on the same user account but on a different computer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, (as long as it is also Windows 10) you can download the game as much as you want. However, if you want to play online on both computers at the same time, you would have to have [two accounts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123923/can-both-my-boys-have-a-user-on-minecraft-pc/124000#124000).