# Is it possible to have two minecraft accounts on one mojang account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I was going to use Multi-MC to test out a mod to see if it would work in multiplayer, but then i realized: "Wait, i have to make a second Minecraft account." So i did that, but even though i already have the game on one account, its making me re-buy the game to be able to test this out. Does anyone have a solution for this? It would mean a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately, you will have to buy a new Minecraft account in order to play with two different accounts.** One possible reason Minecraft might do this is so that people cannot illegitimately give out free Minecraft licenses to others. I found this answer from a [previous answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/123926/267115) to a related question.

Comment: why is this answer downvoted?

Comment: @Jmooroof Not sure. I gave the correct information as well.

Comment: We're confused of @user275705's question. In one context, it's answering the question, in another - It's nonsense.

Comment: @aytimothy out of curiosity, what would the other context be?

Comment: "Is it possible to have two Minecraft accounts (copies of the game) on one Mojang account?" and "Can I play as two players on the one Minecraft account?"