# How can I make a Minecraft offline LAN server using bukkit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My boyfriend and I recently lost internet, typing this from phone and no it can't do hotspot, and me and my boyfriend want to still be able to play on the little Bukkit server I set up for us. But since we lost the internet he can't access it. Is there any way we can make it to where he can? Do we possibly have to wire our computers together to do it? I have Bukkit set up to run offline so that I stop getting the server maintnence message. Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated. Or are we out of luck til we get net back?

Answer (score 8):

If you are in the same network (i.e. connected to the same router and it is set up so you two are really in the same network) you could start the bukkit server on your computer and he can connect using your local IP address.

To get your local IP address, you can use the command prompt.
I am assuming you are using windows as your OS. If not, please tell me and i will edit my answer accordingly.
I am also assuming that you don't know much about computers. I don't want to anger you in any way so of you do understand much about computers, just ignore this fact.

Now, to open the command prompt, you can open the start menu (or the metro menu, when in Windows 8) and then type `cmd` and hit the <kbd>enter</kbd> key.
In the command prompt then you can simply type `ipconfig /all` and again hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.
You will see some information about your network configuration. Now it is important to know which way you are connected to the network: LAN or WLAN?
If you are connected via LAN look out for the entry starting with **Ethernet**. If you are using WLAN look out for an entry starting with **Wireless** (names may differ since i am using a non-english system).
Either way, the entry block should then containa line with a value **IPv4-Address**. This is your local network IP address that your boyfriend needs to connect to the server running on your computer.

Please don't forget:
You still need a way to start minecraft and the server has to run in offline mode!
[Here is a video that might help with that.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fat7E9Tn7Bg)
[This Question should cover the player name problem.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74263/how-do-i-change-my-player-name-in-minecraft-multiplayer-in-offline-mode-in-windo)

If you are still having troubles please leave a comment and i will see what i can do.

Comment: To get only IPv4 address from ipconfig you can invoke `ipconfig | find "IPv4"` or just throw `arp -a`. Anyway, it should be possible to connect by computer name if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @PTwr you can basically use the computer name, yes, but that "only" works if the DNS in the network works correctly. This _should_ be the case, but often enough i witnessed it is not.

Comment: We don't have internet at all so cant connect to WLAN. Our router won't even let the computers talk since we don't have net, I tried to ping him it got mad at me. If that helps more. Cause I tries what you suggested and it didn't work. We're also using laptops, and we have a cross over cable if that is needed.

Comment: @Moonlyre If you have Vista/7 you can [easily create adhoc wireless network on host computer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-computer-to-computer-adhoc-network#1TC=windows-7), with 8/8.1 it is [much harder](http://tipsandtricksforum.com/thread-210.html) for no good reason. You can always try to switch your router in `bridge` mode, but your mileage can vary from model to model (good router do not need internet to work properly but I have seen some weird ones).

Comment: @PTwr i have never seen a router that does not work without internet. When internet drops, it still should be able to support basic LAN. But if you say you've seen such mysterious behavior before, well, i can only say: never buy cheap crap ;) Thx for mentioning adhoc wireless.  
Moonlyre: You _could_ try to use the crossover cable but that might involve some setup work on both computers to work.

Comment: We got our router for free when we got frontier. He has windows 7 and I have 8. We also realized cross over cable won't work since my laptop, free from itt tech, has no Ethernet port. Also has a slot for a cd drive but mother board doesn't support a cd drive. Anyways I will look up what you suggested. And I will also look up how to switch the router to bridge mode.

Comment: Oops just realized I forgot to mention we are running the server from the only desktop in the.house and trying to play it on our laptops.

Comment: @Moonlyre You can either get USB dongle with Ethernet (cable) for laptop or Wifi (do not get micro-size, they overheat and have poor signal range) for PC. Although it is possible to merge wifi with cable into single with [Network Bridge](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783728(v=ws.10).aspx), equipping  PC with wifi for AdHoc network would be easier (and wireless!). As this question stands now, you might be better of asking on Superuser how to setup LAN on your router.