# Internal Exception: java.new.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I have done all required steps to run a Minecraft beta 1.5_01 server, but when I type "localhost" into multiplayer bar a "Logging In" sign appears and does not go away. 
After about a minute, I get an error that says: `Internal Exception: java.new.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: would you kindly post your server log and config file online so that we can diagnose it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had run into a similar issue once before. From what I can recall, the issue was not with your server, rather it's an issue with authenticating with minecraft.net - even if you're connecting to localhost it still routes the username through that server.

What I did to resolve it for me in the meantime:

1. Stop the server if it's already running
2. Navigate to the folder where you have the server files
3. Open up server.properties
4. Find the line that says online-mode=true, change this to false
5. Save the file
6. Relaunch the server, see if it connects

Hope this helps!

Comment: Should that be the cases, the answers [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/15036/88) might come in handy as well

Answer (score 0):

Open up the server.properties and delete everything inside, and replace with this. Customized to your willing of couse...

Here's what is should be:

```
level-name=world
hellworld=false
spawn-monsters=true
online-mode=false
spawn-animals=true
max-players=20
server-ip=
pvp=true
server-port=25565
white-list=false
```

MAKE SURE server-ip= IS BLANK! There is no need to set it. You're probably doing 192.168.0.4 or similar. Leave it blank.

Comment: If he was using something like 192.168.0.4 etc he wouldn't have gotten the "logging in" sign